# Types in MySQL: BigInt(20) vs Int(20)

Tags: mysql, types

I was wondering what the difference between `BigInt`, `MediumInt`, and `Int` are... it would seem obvious that they would allow for larger numbers; however, I can make an `Int(20)` or a `BigInt(20)` and that would make seem that it is not necessarily about size.

Some insight would be awesome, just kind of curious. I have been using **MySQL** for a while and trying to apply business needs when choosing types, but I never understood this aspect.

Answer (score 656, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html

- `INT` is a four-byte signed integer.
- `BIGINT` is an eight-byte signed integer.

They each accept no more and no fewer values than can be stored in their respective number of bytes. That means 2<sup>32</sup> values in an `INT` and 2<sup>64</sup> values in a `BIGINT`.

The 20 in `INT(20)` and `BIGINT(20)` means almost nothing.  It's a hint for display width. It has nothing to do with storage, nor the range of values that column will accept.

Practically, it affects only the `ZEROFILL` option:

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( bar INT(20) ZEROFILL );
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (1234);
SELECT bar from foo;

+----------------------+
| bar                  |
+----------------------+
| 00000000000000001234 |
+----------------------+
```

It's a common source of confusion for MySQL users to see `INT(20)` and assume it's a size limit, something analogous to `CHAR(20)`. This is not the case.

Comment: Wow, this post cleared up my confusion on this subject perfectly. Seems like an odd choice by the developers - as I would have guessed it was width + max value, or bits/etc.

Comment: ` it affects only the ZEROFILL option:` now my curiosity ends

Comment: I really wish that they had designed the syntax with the display with on ZEROFILL instead of INT.  Example: `bar INT ZEROFILL(20)`. It would have been a lot more clear. But that decision was made a long time ago, and changing it now would break millions of database installations.

Comment: I agree this is very confusing. I was under the impression that number was the limit this whole time. Even worried about making some numbers smaller when I knew the data would be within a certain range.

Comment: @jDub9, yes, and it's even more confusing that NUMERIC/DECIMAL take a precision argument that *does* affect the range of values and the size of the column.

Comment: @BillKarwin "But that decision was made a long time ago, and changing it now would break millions of database installations" - I don't see why the `bar INT ZEROFILL (20) couldn't be **added** as an option without removing the old syntax?

Comment: @Vérace, But if you wanted to export that table structure and run it against an older version of MySQL from before you implemented that change, the syntax would not be recognized.

Comment: @BillKarwin - touché - but, the same would be true if you tried to restore a MySQL 8 database that made use of Window functions or generated fields onto a 5.6 instance - it's rare that people "backgrade"!

Comment: Well, as the saying goes, "pull requests welcome." :-)

Answer (score 45):

The number in parentheses in a type declaration is *display width*, which is unrelated to the range of values that can be stored in a data type. Just because you can declare `Int(20)` does not mean you can store values up to 10^20 in it:

> [...] This optional display width may be used by applications to display integer values having a width less than the width specified for the column by left-padding them with spaces. ...
>
> **The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column, nor the number of digits that are displayed for values having a width exceeding that specified for the column.** For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range allowed by three characters are displayed using more than three characters.

For a list of the maximum and minimum values that can be stored in each MySQL datatype, see **[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)**.

Answer (score 21):

[Quote](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2008-March/018522.html):

> The "BIGINT(20)" specification isn't a digit limit.  It just means that when the data is displayed, if it uses less than 20 digits it will be left-padded with zeros. 2^64 is the hard limit for the BIGINT type, and has 20 digits itself, hence BIGINT(20) just means everything less than 10^20 will be left-padded with spaces on display.

Comment: 2^64 (unsigned) actually has 21 digits.  BIGINT(20) is dangerous.  People who use it seem to justify their usage on the idea that 2^64 fits in 20 decimal digits.  If that's the case, why specify a width limit at all?  As it turns out, that's also not correct.  21 digits are needed to properly display 2^64.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt Unless I'm mistaken, 2^64 = 18446744073709551616, which has 20 digits. What makes you say it has 21?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is only one small difference is when you are trying to insert value which is out of range.

> In examples I'll use `401421228216`, which is `101110101110110100100011101100010111000` (length **39** characters)

- If you have `INT(20)` for system this means allocate in memory minimum 20 bits. But if you'll insert value that bigger than `2^20`, it will be stored successfully, only if it's less then `INT(32) -> 2147483647` (or `2 * INT(32) -> 4294967295` for `UNSIGNED`)

**Example:**

```
mysql> describe `test`;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES (401421228216);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1

mysql> SET sql_mode = '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES (401421228216);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0,06 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `test`;
+------------+
| id         |
+------------+
| 4294967295 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

- If you have `BIGINT(20)` for system this means allocate in memory minimum 20 bits. But if you'll insert value that bigger than `2^20`, it will be stored successfully, if it's less then `BIGINT(64) -> 9223372036854775807` (or `2 * BIGINT(64) -> 18446744073709551615` for `UNSIGNED`)

**Example:**

```
mysql> describe `test`;
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES (401421228216);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,04 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `test`;
+--------------+
| id           |
+--------------+
| 401421228216 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's give an example for int(10) one with zerofill keyword, one not, the table likes that:

```
create table tb_test_int_type(
    int_10 int(10),
    int_10_with_zf int(10) zerofill,
    unit int unsigned
);
```

Let's insert some data:

```
insert into tb_test_int_type(int_10, int_10_with_zf, unit)
values (123456, 123456,3147483647), (123456, 4294967291,3147483647) 
;
```

Then

```
select * from tb_test_int_type; 

# int_10, int_10_with_zf, unit
'123456', '0000123456', '3147483647'
'123456', '4294967291', '3147483647'
```

We can see that

- with keyword `zerofill`, num less than 10 will fill 0, but without `zerofill` it won't
- Secondly with keyword `zerofill`, int_10_with_zf becomes unsigned int type, if you insert a minus you will get error `Out of range value for column.....`. But you can insert minus to int_10. Also if you insert 4294967291 to int_10 you will get error `Out of range value for column.....`

Conclusion:

1. int(X) without keyword `zerofill`, is equal to int range -2147483648~2147483647
2. int(X) with keyword `zerofill`, the field is equal to unsigned int range 0~4294967295, if num's length is less than X it will fill 0 to the left

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add one more point is, if you are storing a really large number like 902054990011312 then one can easily see the difference of `INT(20)` and `BIGINT(20)`. It is advisable to store in `BIGINT`.