# What is the difference between an INT of length 20 and BIGINT of length 20 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I understand int stores about 4 bytes and bigint stores about 8 bytes in MySQL

Since one can specify the length of each field in MySQL, Will an int(20) takeup the same space as a bigint(20)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Types in MySQL: BigInt(20) vs Int(20) etcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20-etcc)

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, I could'nt find the question on a stackoverflow search, Thanks!

Comment: In short, there's no meaningful difference between `int(20)` and `int(10)`. There's a big difference between `INT` and `BIGINT`, however. Check [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

The number of bytes occupied by a value is determined by the type.  You can see the list of numeric types and their sizes [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html).

In addition, MySQL supports "attributes" on numeric types.  The `(20)` is a display width on output.  The attributes are explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html).

So, for your example, the storage occupied by the fields is different because the types being used are different.