# MySql BigInt() contains errors

Tags: mysql

I need a column to store credit card numbers and the int size isn't sufficient. However, I keep getting the following message, when trying to set the data type to a bigInt. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: _“I need a column to store credit card numbers”_ – store them as strings; they aren’t really “numbers” anyway.

Comment: Or better yet, don't store them at all. PCI-DSS will eat you alive for that.

Comment: thanks, but this is just a practice project. No real ssn or creditCard

Comment: Numbers should be used where arithmetic operations on the data makes sense. You could not add two credit card *numbers*, or divide a phone *number* by 3. As @CBroe said, not everything that is represented with digits is a number.

Comment: `BIGINT` or `BIGINT(16)`  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour, that was a great point to make that I'd never thought of before.

Comment: Answers posted are correct. But FYI you should know that the argument to INT or BIGINT is nearly meaningless. You don't need it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3135854/20860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use integers for credit cards. It's not meant to be treated as a numerical data.

Technical reason is that the card number can have a leading zero, which would get truncated.

Use strings.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the brackets, it will work.

Use `BIGINT`

instead of `BIGINT()`