# How improve query speed with bigdata ? Mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

The table structure is as follows:

[image]

When I run this query, the execute time is about 2-3 minutes:

```
select id,name,infohash,files from tb_torrent where id between 0 and 10000;
```

There's just over 200,000 data, why is the execution so slow? And how to fix it?

Comment: `20W+`? Does `W` here stand for "webscale"?

Comment: just 20 0000 .. sorry i'll change this , make it clear .

Comment: is it 20 something or 2 hundred thousand? still not clear...

Comment: Does `id` really have to be a `BIGINT`? and does it really need 255 display digits?

Comment: I think this is a Chinese counting unit, right @J.Joe? :P If so, see if my edit looks better.

Comment: You know that [the length of an INT or BIGINT means nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20/3135854#3135854), right?

Comment: And unless you're planning on having 10^20 rows in the table, an `INT UNSIGNED` would be more than sufficient for 200,000 rows, and several orders of magnitude beyond.

Comment: thanks for editing , you are right this is a Chinese counting unit . @icedwater

Comment: I'm not sure what your say , you mean thd 'id' type bigint is not suitable for this ?  And what type mapping the INT UNSIGHNED ,  if i change the type , is right helpful ? @EJP

Comment: Smaller index columns are faster. Unless you're planning on > 4Gig rows over the life of the table you can use INT UNSIGNED. At least try it now, if it doesn't help by all means put it back to BIGINT.

Comment: I've try , but still slow ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unnecessary use of BIGint is not enough to explain the sluggishness.  Let's look for other issues.

Does that "key" icon mean that there is an index on `id`?  Perchance is it `PRIMARY KEY`?

What `ENGINE` is in use?  If it is MyISAM, then you have the drawback of the PK not being 'clustered' with the data, thereby making the 10K lookups slower.

What will you do with 10K rows?  Think of the networks costs.  And the memory costs in the client.

But maybe this is the real problem...  If this is InnoDB, and if the `TEXT` columns are "big", then the values are stored "off record".  This leads to another disk hit to get any big text values.  Change them to some realistic max len of `VARCHAR(...)`.

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Did you time the query twice?  (The first time would be I/O-bound; the second *might* be hitting cache.  How big (in MB or GB) is the table?

Comment: oh you're awesome !!!， thanks a lot , as you say the problem is network costs . My server only support 1M ， so when transfer the 10K data is so solw .  :)