# MySQL: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails when referencing UID

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables : `tbl_usr_info` which has a `UID` which is a primary key and auto-increment and `tbl_login_info` which has a `LoginID` (primary) and the `UID` along with some other information like timestamps etc.

I'm trying to reference UID from `tbl_login_info` with UID in `tbl_usr_info` by running this sql statement

```
CONSTRAINT `uid-info/login` FOREIGN KEY (`UID`) REFERENCES `tbl_usr_info` (`UID`)
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (CONSTRAINT `uid-info/login` FOREIGN KEY (`UID`) REFERENCES `tbl_usr_info` (`UID`))

`tbl_usr_info table`

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_usr_info` (
  `UID` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`tbl_usr_login table`

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_usr_login` (
      `LoginID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `UID` int(50) NOT NULL,
      `ip_address` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
      `device` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
      `time_stamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`LoginID`)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Is it the order in which I'm referencing it that's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your foreign key constraint and it works without error for me. But my tables were empty.

One of the most common types of failures for a foreign key constraint is that when you create the constraint, the child table contains some values that are not present in the parent table. The foreign key constraint cannot be satisfied in that case, so creation of the constraint fails.

You can check for unmatched UID values:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_usr_login AS l
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_usr_info AS i
  ON l.UID = i.UID
WHERE i.UID is NULL;
```

---

P.S.: This is tangential to your question, but I notice you're using `INT(50)`. The argument to INT doesn't mean what you think it means. INT(50) does NOT mean you can store 50 digits. See my answer to [Types in MySQL: BigInt(20) vs Int(20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20/3135854#3135854)

Comment: I had some UID which was `0` and there was no user with `UID = 0` in my tbl_usr_info. That was the issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To enable `foreign key`, child and parent column definitions must match along with some other conditions.

In your problem case, following steps should resolve it:

1. create user table.
2. create login info table.
3. add index/key on the `UID` column in login table.
4. now, add referential constraint on it.

**Refer to**:
Mysql: Using foreign key constraints:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html