# Hibernate unable to add foreign key constraint

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have already created database and all tables with all foreign key constraints. But when I run the spring boot application hibernate is throwing error

> Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table
>   tlp_client add constraint FKfd2km387c8s4oou769dmw5t94 foreign key
>   (u_frn_address_id) references tlp_address (a_id)]

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tlp_client")
public class ClientModel {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "c_id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "c_name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "c_description")
   private String description;

   @Column(name = "c_web_url")
   private String webUrl;

   @Column(name = "c_created_at")
   private Calendar createdAt;

   @Column(name = "c_is_active")
   private Boolean isActive;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "u_frn_created_by", referencedColumnName = "u_id")
   private UserModel createdBy;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "u_frn_address_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id")
   private AddressModel address;

    }
   // getters and setters ...
}
```

**SQL for `ClientModel`**

```
create table tlp_client (
   c_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
   c_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   c_description varchar(255), 
   c_web_url varchar(255),
   c_created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   c_is_active TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,

   c_frn_created_by INT(11),
   c_frn_address_id INT(11),

   PRIMARY KEY (c_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (c_frn_address_id) REFERENCES tlp_address (a_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (c_frn_created_by) REFERENCES tlp_user (u_id)
);
```

**SQL for`AddressModel`**

```
create table tlp_address (
   a_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
   a_address varchar(255),
   a_city varchar(255),
   a_state varchar(255),
   a_country varchar(255),
   a_zip varchar(8),

   PRIMARY KEY (a_id)
);
```

My Question is, I have already created all the tables and still why hibernate is trying to create tables?

**`application.properties`**

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.pool.size=20
server.port=8090
```

**UPDATE**
I ran the application by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` in `application.properties`, now it is throwing the error

> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [a_id] in
>   table [tlp_address]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting
>   [bigint (Types#BIGINT)]

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the original problem went away with the setting

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

The new problem is because `hibernate` is unable to change column type. It is not possible -afaik- anyway without dropping and re-creating the column (or whole table)

You have in your `ClientModel`

```
@Column(name = "c_id")
private Long id; // Long maps to bigint 8 bytes
```

However in your create script you have

```
c_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT, -- int is 4 bytes
```

To get `Long` value to fit in the column it should be `bigint` but you have created it as `int`. Change it to `bigint`

```
c_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

and re-create table

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5634147/6413377) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135854/6413377) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to a simple mistake I made. In the sql scripts, I have field `c_frn_addres_id`, but in the entity class, I was mapping it to `u_frn_address_id`. So after changing `u_frn_address_id` to `c_frn_address_id`, it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

"Hibernate is trying to create tables", because do the configuration with the proeprty spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto. Let change it's value like this

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

You also refer to the working example [Spring Boot JPA One to Many Relationship Mapping](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example.html)

Comment: I did that also, but it is still showing same error

Comment: It's so weird. Actually, you just have java entities enough then Hibernate/JPA will create/update tables which maps your entities.

Comment: Actually this is the first time I am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

This can have **many reasons**.
For example, in the MYSQL database, you can use the link below :
[enter link description here](https://dzone.com/articles/dealing-with-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

One of the **common reasons** that may occur in database development is that the **type of columns in the code and the database are not the same**.

For example :
**In your entity, "id" field might result in "int(11)",but the current database expect "bigint(20)".**

This interference will result in the following error :

```
Hibernate unable to add foreign key constraint
```

Finally check step by step your primary-foreign keys.

I hope this will help you...