# Error executing DDL "alter table if exists add constraint foreign key () references" via JDBC Statement

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I try to run my projet but this error is raised :

`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists public.modele add constraint FKkgs06iwjdxp4r2pnb9num8cgd foreign key (objet_modele_by_objet_id) references public.objet_modele"` via JDBC Statement

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "modele", schema = "public", catalog = "pfeDb")
    public class ModeleEntity {
    private String idModele;
    private String nomModele;
      private ObjetModeleEntity objetModeleByObjetId;
     @Id
     public String getIdModele() {
        return idModele;
      }
public void setIdModele(String idModele) {
    this.idModele = idModele;
}

   public String getNomModele() {
    return nomModele;
}

public void setNomModele(String nomModele) {
    this.nomModele = nomModele;
}
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "objetModeleByObjetId")
public ObjetModeleEntity getObjetModeleByObjetId() {
    return objetModeleByObjetId;
}

public void setObjetModeleByObjetId(ObjetModeleEntity 
 objetModeleByObjetId) {
    this.objetModeleByObjetId = objetModeleByObjetId;
}
}
```

and the second entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "objet_modele", schema = "public", catalog = "pfeDb")
  public class ObjetModeleEntity {
   private int objetId;
   private Integer posX;
   private Integer posY;
   private Integer largeur;
    private Integer hauteur;
    private Collection<ModeleEntity> modelesByObjetId;
    @Id
  public int getObjetId() {
     return objetId;
  }

 public void setObjetId(int objetId) {
    this.objetId = objetId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "pos_x", nullable = true)
public Integer getPosX() {
    return posX;
}

public void setPosX(Integer posX) {
    this.posX = posX;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "pos_y", nullable = true)
public Integer getPosY() {
    return posY;
}

public void setPosY(Integer posY) {
    this.posY = posY;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "largeur", nullable = true)
public Integer getLargeur() {
    return largeur;
}

public void setLargeur(Integer largeur) {
    this.largeur = largeur;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "hauteur", nullable = true)
public Integer getHauteur() {
    return hauteur;
}
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "objetModeleByObjetId")
public Collection<ModeleEntity> getModelesByObjetId() {
    return modelesByObjetId;
}

public void setModelesByObjetId(Collection<ModeleEntity> modelesByObjetId) 
{
    this.modelesByObjetId = modelesByObjetId;
}
}
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605790/hibernate-unable-to-add-foreign-key-constraint) might help you .

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm it was a version conflict between the data base and those in pom.xml

Comment: @imaneBlh glad you've figured it out and solved it.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm thank you