# MySql doesn't accept boolean as its column datatype

Tags: mysql, database, boolean

I have a Java program which stores data in MySQL database in two states. For this purpose I wanted to use `BOOLEAN`. But whenever I enter `BOOLEAN` it's getting changed into `TINYINT`.

Is there any other way to store data in two states?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL uses `TINYINT(1)` to mimic the behaviour of Boolean type, so make sure you use `TINYINT(1)` as the data type of your column, not `TINYINT`.

Alternatively, you can use `BOOL` or `BOOLEAN` which are both synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`.

Similarly, the values `TRUE` and `FALSE` are merely aliases for `1` and `0`, respectively in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for replying! so how should i get the value back with the help of ResultSet object? I meant which method should i use? getInt()?

Comment: If you use `TINYINT(1)` (not `TINYINT`) like I said, you should be able to get Boolean values. If you use `getInt()`, you will have to convert it to Boolean in your code, which is pretty simple with casting.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have a native boolean type.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html says:

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true:

This means the "boolean" type is still an 8-bit signed integer, and [the `(1)` syntax is not a size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20/3135854#3135854). It doesn't prevent the column from storing integer values from -128 to 127. It's up to you to refrain from storing those values.

MySQL also supports a `BIT` data type: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html

The MySQL JDBC driver translates `BIT(1)` into java.lang.Boolean. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html for JDBC data type mappings.

But the BIT data type has had some bugs in its history. I avoid using it.

Bit probably won't save any space, anyway, if that's what you are hoping for. If you had a bunch of BIT columns defined consecutively in your table, they would be stored compactly, up to 8 columns per byte. But the minimum storage is still 1 byte, so if you had 1 BIT column, it would still take a whole byte.

---

Re your questions:

It doesn't take much code to test this out.

I created a test table and put one row of values in it:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `b` bool DEFAULT '1', /* this is a synonym for TINYINT(1) */
  `ti` tinyint DEFAULT '1',
  `tiu` tinyint unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `si` smallintDEFAULT '1',
  `siu` smallint unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `i` int DEFAULT '1',
  `iu` int unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `bi` bigint DEFAULT '1',
  `biu` bigint unsigned DEFAULT '1'
);

INSERT INTO foo () VALUES ();
```

Then I called some JDBC code and used `getObject()` for each column, and asked it to tell me what data type it returned:

```
    stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM foo");
    while (rs.next()) {

        Object b = rs.getObject("b");
        System.out.println("b ("+b.getClass().getSimpleName()+"):\t" + b);

        Object ti = rs.getObject("ti");
        System.out.println("ti ("+ti.getClass().getSimpleName()+"):\t" + ti);

        Object tiu = rs.getObject("tiu");
        System.out.println("tiu ("+tiu.getClass().getSimpleName()+"):\t" + tiu);

        Object si = rs.getObject("si");
        System.out.println("si ("+si.getClass().getSimpleName()+"):\t" + si);

        Object siu = rs.getObject("siu");
        System.out.println("siu ("+siu.getClass().getSimpleName()+"):\t" + siu);

        Object i = rs.getObject("i");
        System.out.println("i ("+i.getClass().getSimpleName()+"):\t" + i);

        Object iu = rs.getObject("iu");
        System.out.println("iu ("+iu.getClass().getSimpleName()+"):\t" + iu);

        Object bi = rs.getObject("bi");
        System.out.println("bi ("+bi.getClass().getSimpleName()+"):\t" + bi);

        Object biu = rs.getObject("biu");
        System.out.println("biu ("+biu.getClass().getSimpleName()+"):\t" + biu);
    }
```

Output:

```
b (Boolean):    true
ti (Integer):   1
ti2 (Integer):  1
tiu (Integer):  1
si (Integer):   1
siu (Integer):  1
i (Integer):    1
iu (Long):  1
bi (Long):  1
biu (BigInteger):   1
```

I'm testing with MySQL Connector/J 5.1.44.

So it seems that `TINYINT(1)` is handled specially by the JDBC driver. It automatically converts it to a java.lang.Boolean.

Again, `TINYINT(1)` has no real effect on the range of possible values in MySQL. It's an 8-bit signed integer type. But the JDBC driver has special code to look for the `(1)` length option and it uses that as an advisory to make it cast to a java.lang.Boolean.

java.lang.Integer is okay up to the unsigned 32-bit INT, then it has to use java.lang.Long to handle the unsigned INT. Then a BigInteger for an unsigned BIGINT. Java integer types are not unsigned, so to handle the larger values of an unsigned INT or BIGINT, Java has to use the larger Integer type.

Comment: Thank you for replying! If i use datatype as TINYINT, what ResultSet class's method i should use to retrieve the data? getInt() or something else?

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean` and `TINYINT(1)` are synonyms in `mysql`, meaning that you can use them interchangeably without raising any problem.