# mysql result is different depending on if queried value is via prepared statement or in sql string

Tags: php, mysql

I have encountered a problem in **PHP** where if I use an integer as a parameter via prepared statements, it doesn't work - but if it is just pasted into the **SQL** string, it works perfectly.

For example, this will return an incorrect count (3):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE x = :num");

$num = 1556555454;
$query->bindParam(":num", $num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

But this will return it perfectly fine, with the correct row count (2):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE x = 1556555454");
```

As far as I'm aware, they should both work the exact same - but both queries return different results (ironically, the correct way is returning the incorrect answer).

Comment: Is this the exact number causing the issue? It almost just so fits a 32 bit int, else it might become a float. If so, supply a string. MySQL can typecast on its own.

Comment: What data type is "x" in your database table? Prepared qureis are very smart and will cast as a string or integer as needed. Also consider typcasting the variable in your `bindParam(":num", (int)$num,...`

Comment: Except in very special cases, you don't need to do this at all. Skip the binding and just do `$query->execute([":num" => 1556555454]);`

Comment: @mario that number is unix timestamp :) and was just the one I happened to be testing with at the time, but yes - all unix timestamps seem to be returning the same value when done through prepared statements

Comment: @danielson317 It's an integer with a length of 11. I've tried doing `(int)`, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: @GROVER. Integer data types have a fixed length of 32 or 64 bit based on your underlying OS. by telling me the length is 11 I would assume it is actually a string.

Comment: In `INT(11)`, the 11 means almost nothing. It's not a length limit. It doesn't change the max value of the `INT`. `INT` is always 4 bytes, `BIGINT` is always 8 bytes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20/3135854#3135854

Comment: Use `UNSIGNED INT`, that will be big enough for a Unix timestamp.

Comment: @GROVER. Any chance that `$num` is changed after the prepare but before the execute?  When using `bindParam()` the bound value will change as the variable changes until the query is executed.  As opposed to `bindValue()` which only uses the value of the variable at the time of the binding.