# Syntax error when creating custom mysql function

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Trying to create a stored function but keep getting the same error.

I've tried a different body, changing `integer` to `INT` with/out `(11)`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION f_media (@dag INT, @week INT, @medium_naam varchar)
RETURNS integer

BEGIN 
    DECLARE result INT(11);

    SELECT result=COUNT(medium_name) FROM `TABLE 4` WHERE WEEK(date) = @week AND DAYOFWEEK(date) = dag AND medium_name == @medium_naam GROUP BY date;

    RETURN result;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

This is the exact error:

> MySQL said:
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>
> '@dag INT, @week INT, @medium_naam varchar)
>   RETURNS integer
>
> BEGIN
>   DECLA' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting the `@` sigil in front of your function arguments. This is common if you're using Microsoft SQL Server, but MySQL has different syntax than Microsoft SQL Server.

`@dag` is called a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). It has session scope.

`dag` is a [local variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-variables.html), either a function argument or one you create in a `BEGIN/END` block with `DECLARE`.

They are two different variables.

Because the variables don't have sigils, you have to be careful that you [don't name a variable the same as one of the columns of the tables you query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html) (you almost did so in the case of `medium_naam`). To resolve this ambiguity, I have the habit of adding a prefix of "in_" to the function arguments.

There is no `==` operator in SQL. [Use `=` for comparison](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal).

You shouldn't use `GROUP BY` if you intend your query will store a single result into a scalar variable.

Assigning the result to a variable in an expression can be done with `:=` but not `=`. But you should avoid this usage because it [may be removed from MySQL in a future version](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). I suggest you use `INTO` syntax instead.

Don't bother with the length in the `INT(11)` type. [It means nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20/3135854#3135854).

Here's a corrected function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_media (in_dag INT, in_week INT, in_medium_naam varchar)
RETURNS INT

BEGIN 
    DECLARE result INT;

    SELECT COUNT(medium_name) INTO result
    FROM `TABLE 4` 
    WHERE WEEK(date) = in_week 
     AND DAYOFWEEK(date) = in_dag 
     AND medium_name = in_medium_naam;

    RETURN result;
END
```

Comment: Hello Bill! I do the exact function syntax but I still have a syntax error in ```DECLARE result INT``` I don't know why. I using MySQL MariaDB and MySQL workbeanch thanks.

Comment: I can't guess what you did or what the exact error message is. I suggest you ask a new question and provide details. Also I don't use MariaDB and I consider it to be a different product from MySQL, because it forked ten years ago and it has been growing less compatible with MySQL since then.