# Why is MySQL 5.7 using MAMP so much faster than local MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, mamp, mysql-8.0

I have just moved from running my local MySQL database from using MAMP-supported MYSQL v5.7.30 to a "normal" local MySQL installation of v8.0.22. While the reason for the switch was that I wanted to use CTEs, I was also hoping for a performance increase, as is frequently reported.

While the performance ist slightly better (10-20%) for most of my queries, the performance for a simple `SELECT count(*) from mytable;` takes about twice as long: **3.8s** on MAMP-MySQL 5.7.30 vs. **7.5s** on MySQL 8.0.22. This is on a table with 15m rows and 12 columns, 1 PK, 1 indexed column (besides the PK), no FK.

The tables should be exactly the same as I migrated them using the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard.

Searching Stackoverflow for possible performance tweaks it looks like the usual suspects may not be set to ideal values (using the out-of-the-box settings of MySQL), but they are at least  identical between my two databases:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'; # 134217728 = 128MB
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_file_size';  # 50331648 = 48MB
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_instances';  # 1
```

So the question is: Why is the performance for COUNT(*) statements so much worse, and how can I get the performance out of MySQL 8.0 that I get out of MySQL 5.7?

*As this was asked in the comments: For both 5.7 and 8.0 I use the **same machine**, which is a fairly recent laptop with a 2.2 GHz intel i7 processor and 16GB of RAM, running macOS Catalina.*

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

EDIT: As requested in the comments, here are a couple more details:

1 - `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable`

For 5.7:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `var1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `var2` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `var3` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `var4` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `var5` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `var6` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `var7` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `var8` text,
  `var9` text,
  `var10` text,
  `var11` text,
  `var12` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`var1`),
  KEY `idx_var12` (`var12`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

For 8.0:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `var1` int NOT NULL,
  `var2` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `var3` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `var4` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `var5` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `var6` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `var7` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `var8` text,
  `var9` text,
  `var10` text,
  `var11` text,
  `var12` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`var1`),
  KEY `idx_var12` (`var12`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

2 - `EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) from mytable;`

For both 8.0 and 5.7:

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'mytable', NULL, 'index', NULL, 'idx_var12', '5', NULL, '15480019', '100.00', 'Using index'
```

3 - `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`

For 5.7:

```
# Id, User, Host, db, Command, Time, State, Info
'682', 'root', 'localhost:64503', 'testdb', 'Sleep', '178', '', NULL
'683', 'root', 'localhost:64504', 'testdb', 'Query', '0', 'starting', 'SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST'
```

For 8.0:

```
# Id, User, Host, db, Command, Time, State, Info
'5', 'event_scheduler', 'localhost', NULL, 'Daemon', '1545', 'Waiting on empty queue', NULL
'8', 'root', 'localhost:65524', 'my_schema', 'Query', '0', 'init', 'SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST'
'9', 'root', 'localhost:65525', 'my_schema', 'Sleep', '284', '', NULL
```

4 - `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name = 'mytable';`

For 5.7:

```
# Name, Engine, Version, Row_format, Rows, Avg_row_length, Data_length, Max_data_length, Index_length, Data_free, Auto_increment, Create_time, Update_time, Check_time, Collation, Checksum, Create_options, Comment
'mytable', 'InnoDB', '10', 'Dynamic', '15480019', '168', '2611986432', '0', '261898240', '6291456', NULL, '2020-11-17 23:03:04', NULL, NULL, 'utf8_general_ci', NULL, '', ''
```

For 8.0:

```
# Name, Engine, Version, Row_format, Rows, Avg_row_length, Data_length, Max_data_length, Index_length, Data_free, Auto_increment, Create_time, Update_time, Check_time, Collation, Checksum, Create_options, Comment
'mytable', 'InnoDB', '10', 'Dynamic', '14009911', '148', '2081423360', '0', '313507840', '6291456', NULL, '2020-11-22 21:03:29', '2020-11-22 21:17:55', NULL, 'utf8_general_ci', NULL, '', ''
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results from EACH MACHINE, A) SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable; and B) EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) from mytable; for comparison.   We do not want to see how you created you table, but the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable; please.

Comment: And please post TEXT results of something similar to HTOP or TOP from your 8.0 equipment.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, added the SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN SELECT to the question - hope that helps.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I have no idea what you mean by "something similar to HTOP or TOP". Notice that both DBs are running on the same machine.

Comment: FWIW, `int(11)` and `int` are the same. MySQL 8.0 finally got rid of the superfluous and confusing size for integers, because it doesn't really matter. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135854/20860

Comment: Then let's try for SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; from MySQL to see what is running on each server.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I've added the resuts for SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; to the question.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you add TEXT results from SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable; from your 8.0 server? From each INSTANCE of MySQL what is result from MySQL Command Prompt of SELECT @@port; ?

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I've added the results from SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable; above (unless there's something else you mean by "*TEXT* results"?). The port is 8889 for MAMP/5.7 and 3306 for  8.0.

Comment: From your 8.0 please post results of SHOW INDEX FROM mytable;

Comment: @WilsonHauck - I have updated the question to reflect my observation that only SELECT COUNT(*) queries are slower, while my other queries are, in fact, slightly faster.

Comment: @Sebastian Would determine time to complete query from 8.0 for SELECT count(var1) from mytable; to compare, please. Do you use EVENT_SCHEDULER functionality in your application? You can find out with SELECT GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%event%'; and post results for evaluation, please. If we can turn EVENT_SCHEDULER OFF, you may free some CPU cycles. See 8.0 ref manual.

Comment: Additional information request from 5.7 instance and 8.0 instance, please.  # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on your single machine supporting both instances? Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; G) STATUS; for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, thanks so much for your input and eagerness to answer my question! As mentioned above, however, I have found out that all queries I've tried so far are in fact FASTER on 8.0, as it should be be. The only exception are SELECT COUNT(*) queries, which inexplicably are slower. But given that things are faster overall I can live with that! Therefore I'm gonna go ahead and close this question. Again, appreciate your efforts!

Comment: The very best to you and your family, Happy Holidays and Stay Safe. For additional speed, post requested data for 8.0 only when time permits, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: That's just how it is.

Long answer: As pointed out in the modified version of the question, I have found out that all queries I've tried are, in fact, *FASTER* on 8.0 than they are on 5.7 - as it should be. The only exception seems to be `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries, which inexplicably are slower. But given that things are faster overall I can live with that.