# why should we set field length while creating sql table?

Tags: mysql

I can't understand why should we set field length while creating SQL table fields.

```
INT(11),
VARCHAR(255),
```

Comment: Some have implications for storage and some for display further explanation can be found in the manual. You might also wonder why they need to be defined at all...

Comment: _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

Data lengths are another form of data validation - they allow you to easily constrain the data in the table and not allow values that are larger than your program's logic would allow.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different cases.

```
INT(11)
```

The "length" of an integer is almost meaningless, and MySQL 8.0 deprecates this syntax. An `INT` is always a 32-bit integer, regardless of the length argument. The only practical use of the length argument is if you use:

```
INT(11) ZEROFILL
```

This pads the number with zeroes *when you fetch it*, not as it is stored. The number is still stored exactly the same as `INT(2)` or `INT(50)`, as a 32-bit integer. See my answer to [Types in MySQL: BigInt(20) vs Int(20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20/3135854#3135854)

```
VARCHAR(255)
```

It's necessary to define a length because that's how data types must work in relational theory. The definition of a data type is "a named, **finite** set of values." It can't be a finite set if the strings have infinite length.

There is also the practical reason: to store a string, MySQL precedes it with one or two bytes encoding the length, so it knows how many characters to read. One byte of length information is used if the length is up to 255. Two bytes of length information is used if the length is up to 65535. That's the maximum length supported for `VARCHAR` in MySQL.