# How do I create a query in Java for auto increment table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I was trying to create an insert query in Java to MySQL server but the thing is it keep asking for value for column "user id" even though I've already define it as AUTO_INCREMENT. I've tried to set the value to NULL too but it said "column user id cannot be null".

From what I know in SQL you don't have to define value for auto increment type right ?

Query:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO 
user(userId, username, password, gender, country, role) 
VALUES(NULL,'"+uu+"', '"+pp+"', '"+gg+"','"+cc+"', '"+rr+"')";
```

Errors :

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'userId' cannot be null
>
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1333)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2106)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1243)
> at main.Connect.updateData(Connect.java:43)
> at main.Regis.actionPerformed(Regis.java:189)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Table definition :

```
|Column  |Type         |Null|key|Default|Extra|
+--------+-------------+----+---+-------+-----+
|userId  |int          |NO  |___|NULL   |     |
|username|varchar(255) |NO  |___|NULL   |     |
|password|varchar(255) |NO  |___|NULL   |     |
|gender  |varchar(255) |NO  |___|NULL   |     |
|country |varchar(255) |NO  |___|NULL   |     |
|role    |varchar(255) |NO  |___|NULL   |     |
```

Note : from the `.sql` file that I get there is alter table code for table user

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
MODIFY `userId` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: can you share tha table definition ? Do `desc user;` and show us by [edit]ing your post

Comment: i really dont know how this stack overflow thing works im new, so im sorry if i break some rules

Comment: Just leave userId out of the insert statement.

Comment: yea i already did that but it said "Field 'userId' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: it sounds like maybe your alter table didn't succeed?  could you edit your question and show (as text, not an image) the output of `show create table users;`?  @azro that provides so much more helpful information than desc

Comment: I mean `show create table user;`

Comment: Also, don't make SQL statements by concatenating strings like that - you are wide open to SQL Injection attacks. Use PreparedStatement with setValue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a column AUTO_INCREMENT unless it's has a key (that is, index) on it. Best if it's a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY.

But I see in your example of describe table, the column is not a key:

```
|Field   |Type         |Null|key|Default|Extra|
|--------|-------------|----|---|-------|-----|
|userId  |int          |NO  |___|NULL   |     |

                             ^^^ ideally this should say "PRI"
```

So your ALTER TABLE to make the column AUTO_INCREMENT probably failed. You can confirm this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `user`\G
```

Do you see the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option next to the `userId` column? I don't think you will.

You can try again to make the column a primary key *and* make it AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
ALTER TABLE `user`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
 MODIFY `userId` INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Don't bother with `INT(255)`. The length argument for an integer is a common source of confusion. [It has almost no purpose or effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135804/types-in-mysql-bigint20-vs-int20/3135854#3135854), and it's [deprecated in MySQL 8.0](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99385).

Don't bother making the column `NOT NULL`. That will happen automatically as you add the PRIMARY KEY constraint.

Don't bother setting the `AUTO_INCREMENT=8`. The next AI value will automatically be set to the highest value in that column, plus one. It can never be less than the greatest value in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, must work if you already defined userId is an auto_increament.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO user(username,password,gender,country,role)  VALUES('"+uu+"', '"+pp+"', '"+gg+"','"+cc+"', '"+rr+"')";
```